# Definition of field of fractions of $p$-adic integers

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am given this definition of the field of fractions of the p-adic integers:

$$Q_p=\left\{ \frac{r}{s} \mid r, s \in Z_p, s \neq 0\right\}$$

How can I show that:

$Q_p$ consists of the sums of the form $\sum_{i=-k}^{\infty} a_ip^i$ ?

Answer (score 3):

A $p$-adic integer can be expressed uniquely in the form
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}p^{i}
$$
where $a_i$ is an integer with $0\le a_i<p$. Moreover, any $p$-adic integer can be written in a unique way as
$$
up^k
$$
with $u$ invertible and $k\ge0$. In particular,
$$
\frac{r}{s}=\frac{r}{up^k}=\frac{u^{-1}r}{p^k}
$$
Write $u^{-1}r=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}p^{i}$ and you're done.

Comment: So, is it like that? $\displaystyle{ \frac{r}{s}=\frac{u^{-1}r}{p^k}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ip^i}{p^k}}=p^{-k} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_ip^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i}p^{i-k}=\sum_{i=-k}^{\infty} a_{i+k} p^i$

Comment: @evinda Yes, good.

Comment: So, do we have to set $b_i=a_{i+k}$ ?

Comment: @evinda Yes, but it's just bookkeeping.

Comment: A ok.. And something else, how can we show that for at least one $i$, the power of $p$ is negative?

Comment: @evinda No, $p$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean that $p$ is a counterexample? I haven't understood it... :/